# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when my application runs from the Debug directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crash

This happens even when the application is not running inside VS2010 as long as the solution that builds the application is open.

The event that triggers the crash in Visual Studio is the creation of a file or directory in a folder that the application is watching using code that in general looks like...

```
private FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher;

fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.FileChangedHandler);
fileSystemWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.FileCreatedHandler);
fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.FileDeletedHandler);
fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(this.FileRenamedHandler);
```

Then the event handlers add appropriate nodes to a custom tree view. For example the File Create handler is...

```
    private void FileCreatedHandler(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(e.FullPath) == true)
        {
            //The new file system item is a directory
            DirectoryChecker(e.FullPath);
            findAllDirectories(e.FullPath);
            findAllFiles(e.FullPath);
        }
        else if (System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath) == true)
        {
            //The new file system item is a file
            string errorMessage = String.Empty;
            if (createResourceNode(e.FullPath, out errorMessage) == false)
            {
                OutputWindow.addMessage(
                    OutputWindow._OutputType.Error,
                    @"Could not add '" + e.FullPath + @"' to the Resource Manager:" +
                        Environment.NewLine +
                        errorMessage,
                    @"Resource Manager");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now what is confusing to me is that this code works fine, the application does not crash, no exceptions, no problems, it runs. However Visual Studio 2010 crashes whenever this block of code executes from the debug directory.

Any thoughts or ideas? I am working around this but it would be nice to be able to run my environment without crashes.

Comment: do you mean your program crashes or visual studio itself does?

Comment: If you have extensions try running the program with them disabled

Comment: I disabled all my extensions as part of my testing. Even uninstalled a couple that wouldn't just disable. And its visual studio that is crashing, the application runs fine.